# Why does Visual Studio (2008 and 2010) put three bytes at the beginning of text and XML files that it creates?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I use Visual Studio (2008 and 2010) to create a new text or XML file, it always includes three strange-looking bytes at the very beginning of the file. These three bytes can't be seen unless you are using a binary editor.

[image: 3 Bytes in text file]

Why are they there and what do they do?

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio from putting them there?

As it stands I cannot use Visual Studio to create XML files because these bytes screw up the parser.

Answer (score 7):

it's **BOM** or [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) this usually happens when you save your file using other encoding especially in **UTF-8** to solve it...

open **File** menu > select **Advanced Save Options** > then select **UTF-8 without signature**

Answer (score 2):

EF BB BF is the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/) [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) - in essence, it's stating that the file is in UTF-8 format.

To permanently remove this, you can use the File -> Advanced Save Options and then select "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001" from the encoding dropdown. (It'll appear quite far down the list).

Answer (score 2):

This is a utf8 byte order mark

see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for more information. It basically states that its a text file in utf8 format. Most text editors recognise it and therefore know how to understand the format of the file.

Is your XML parser hand rolled? All production grade XML parsers I've used have no problem (infact are positively helped) by having a correct BOM.

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2010 you can install the [Fix File Encoding](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/540ac2d8-f881-4794-8b00-810d28257b70) extension and set \.(txt|xml)$ in options to prevent BOM being added.